# Server shares can be listed in Windows File explorer, but net view \\MyServerName returns error 53

Tags: c#, windows, network-share

I am struggling with finding a way to get a list of shares on a Remote Server. The server is a Linux based videoserver that I have no access to what so ever in terms of changing settings etc.
My issue is that after starting the servers client manager software on my local computer, I can list all Shares in a normal file explorer window by just entering \\MyServerName as the path
But all tries to access the list of shares via net view or C# DirectoryInfo(..) returns Error 53.
I have tried all ideas I have found on line:

1. Adding the login in the local machine user account vault
2. `net use \\MyServerName /user:MyID MyPassword`
3. PowerShell Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -computer  | select name, providername (returns RPC-server not available)

The weird thing is that File Explorer has no problem listing the shares!
If I create a DirectoryInfo with one of the existing shares on the server, then it works fine:

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\MyServerName\OneOfTheShares");
```

I am aware that DirectoryInfo cannot use a servername only. It needs a folder. But what I can't understand is why File Explorer can list the shares, but `net view \\MyServerName` can't!

Can anyone please help me with some thoughts?

Comment: Samba share can contain not only folders but also printers, etc... so you can't list it using DirectoryInfo. I consider using WinApi to get a list of the shares.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so being teased by Anton Anpilogov ;-) to take a WinApi aproach to this issue, I found a 16 year old CodeProject by Rob Manderson https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6235/Enumerating-Network-Resources
that put me on the right track :-)
By using WNetEnumResource to enumerate connected server resources filtering them with my known Server name, I can return a list of all shares on that server!

```
result = WNetOpenEnum(scope, type, usage, pRsrc, out handle);
if (result == ErrorCodes.NO_ERROR)
{
    do
    {
        result = WNetEnumResource(handle, ref cEntries, buffer, ref bufferSize);
        if (result == ErrorCodes.NO_ERROR)
        {
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, pRsrc);
            if(pRsrc.lpRemoteName.StartsWith(<MyServerName>))
        {
             Shares.Add(pRsrc.lpRemoteName);
        }
    }
    else if (result != ErrorCodes.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        break;
} while (result != ErrorCodes.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);

WNetCloseEnum(handle);
```

}

The code obviously needs some tidying up, but it works!
Thanx!